# Merge datagrid cells

Tags: asp.net

i have to merge the cells from the cell that does not contain the radio button, to the cell that contains the radio button.

here the  link for the interface

http://i839.photobucket.com/albums/zz316/girish_kolte/untitled.jpg

Comment: Please post your datagrid's HTML. There are a few ways to do this, but having your sample will help.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the TemplateField and here is a [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/%28S%28ywiyuluxr3qb2dfva1z5lgeg%29%29/learn/data-access/tutorial-12-cs.aspx) that explains some of the other fields that GridView offers as well.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvwAirportSchedule" runat="server">
  <Columns>
    ....
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate  HeaderText="Airport">
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rbAirport" runat="server" Visible='<%# (bool)Eval("IsDestination") %>' />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text='<%# Eval("Airport") %>'  />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    ....
  </Columns>  
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: +1. You'll also want to add some style-sheet goodness to right-align the `<asp:Label>`, I expect.

Comment: This is the way to go, as far as *combining* columns, but it appears there are rows where the radio button is not present. It'd be interesting to see what that requirement is, and how it's being handled currently.

Comment: @pcampbell maybe something like this: Visible='<%# (bool)Eval("IsValidAirport") %>'

Answer (score 3):

good answer from David.

One could reduce, by omitting Lable like below

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Airport") %>'  />
```

Comment: I agree, but I wanted to show him how you can have 2 controls in one col. But nice +1.